# ASP.NET MVC 5 Intranet Site Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I'm looking for a little push in the right direction for adding "Roles" to my ASP.NET MVC5 application that is going to be used on our intranet. Currently, I have the project set to use "Windows Authentication" so I can pull their domain username. I have used [Authorize(Role = "")] before, but it's kinda clunky and annoying to maintain. I was wondering if there was a way to do this using the Domain accounts, but having the "Roles" and "Role Membmers" specified in a database so a simple user delegated as an "admin" could manage it. This way the user wouldn't have to log into the page, but still would be able to see different parts of the app based on their "role"

I'm currently doing some reading into ASP.NET Identity 2.0, but I'm not sure if it can accomplish what I want, or if there is a easier way.

Comment: not a single relpy since 2014? That's what stackoverflow is today. To find help here is a struggle. A monster system with unhelpful environment. If you found the answer, what was the solution?

Comment: I had posted my solution, but I guess it was flagged for deletion and deleted.

Comment: This was my solution.

http://www.leapinggorilla.com/Blog/Read/1015/custom-role-providers-with-windows-authentication---part-2-roleprovider-and-integration